# Constructing a Minimal Free resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I had a quick question about my understanding of the construction of a minimal free resolution. Say, my ring is $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ and my ideal is $J = (x^2, xy, xz, y^2).$ Computer computation shows that the minimal free resolution is
$$ 0 \xrightarrow{} A \xrightarrow{d_3} A^4 \xrightarrow{d_2} A^4 \xrightarrow{d_1} A \xrightarrow{} A/J \rightarrow 0,$$

where

$$ d_1 = \begin{pmatrix} x^2 & xy & xz & y^2 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \hspace{1cm}d_2 = \begin{pmatrix} y &0&z&0\\ -x &z&0&y\\ 0 &-y&-x&0\\ 0&0&0&-x \end{pmatrix}, \hspace{1cm}d_3 = \begin{pmatrix} z & x & -y & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T.
$$

Furthermore, I know that a resolution is minimal if and only if we choose a minimal system of generators for the kernel of each map.

So, my question is the following: By the rank-nullity theorem and since the map $d_1$ has rank $1,$ then the kernel should have $3$ generators. So, why do I need $4$ columns in the matrix $d_2$ to make sure this is minimal? Hopefully, my question makes sense? The rank-nullity should apply, but maybe it doesn't? A more broad question, maybe not answerable here, is what am I not understanding? A search shows that this specific question has not been answered here yet.

Comment: rank of $d_2$ is $3$. Because the determinant of the $4\times 4$ matrix is $0$. The rank nullity should be considered in the sense of theory of fitting ideals.

Comment: Actually, I am sorry, does the rank-nullity not apply in this setting? We want to check these are exact as $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps, right?

Comment: The rank nullity can be considered (for example in your case) rank $d_1$+rank $d_2$=4, rank $d_3$+rank $d_2$=4. In this case, we say the rank of the map $d$ is $n$ when $n$ is the largest number such that the ideal generated by all $n\times n$ minors is not $0$.

Comment: Okay, and then, one final question and this may a simple mistake on my part. When I go through constructing the free resolution, I look at $d_1$ and I see the nullity of this map is $3,$ but for various beyond me the kernel of this map is minimally generated by $4$ generators. So what is going on? :(

Comment: Also, it is clear that these are in the Kernel, which is obvious.

Comment: This is similar to rank nullity but in the sense I mentioned above. It is different from the traditional dimension consideration in matrices. You may refer to Eisenbud's commutative algebra chapter 20 about fitting ideals, and especially theorem 20.9 with its remark.